# Why does restarting eclipse improve my running time

Tags: java, eclipse

So I was running some tests and my Java application was slower than expected. I shutdown and restarted eclipse and the running time was improved by a factor of almost 2. What could possibly cause this behavior?

Comment: It may have multiple causes but a very likely is your tests use much heap memory that is not free fast by Eclipse. Restarting the Eclipse frees the memory in a straight way as it terminates the JVM.

Comment: its probably that, the software is very memory intensive.thanks!

Comment: Is it reproducible? Can you rule out that other processes were running or that the system swapped?

Comment: I wasn't doing anything else at the time. The exec.time is never quite the same, but the program is very memory intensive so I a non-determinism with Java garbage collection is probably the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your test does not terminate correctly, so that the process is still running.
You can check with the Eclipse debugger, if the process is still alive.

When Eclipse shuts down, it kills every Java process which was started by Eclipse.